# Vec of Bundle as a Module parameter

Tags: scala, hdl, chisel

I'm writing a [Wishbone Intercon](https://github.com/Martoni/WbPlumbing/blob/master/src/main/scala/wbplumbing/wbplumbing.scala) module to make the address decoding automatically.
I have two Bundle classes that describe Wishbone master and Wishbone slave interface.

```scala
class WbMaster (val dwidth: Int,
                val awidth: Int) extends Bundle {
    val adr_o = Output(UInt(awidth.W))
//...
    val cyc_o = Output(Bool())
}

// Wishbone slave interface
class WbSlave (val dwidth: Int,
               val awidth: Int) extends Bundle {
  val adr_i = Input(UInt(awidth.W))
//...
  val cyc_i = Input(Bool())
}
```

I want to pass these Bundle as parameter to my module Wishbone like following:

```scala
class WbInterconOneMaster(val awbm: WbMaster,
                          val awbs: Vec(WbSlave)) extends Module {
    val io = IO(new Bundle{
      val wbm = Flipped(new WbMaster(awbm.dwidth, awbm.awidth))
      val wbs = Vec(?)
    })
}
```

The objective is to permit a variable number of wishbone slaves and let the module doing the plumbing. Like following:

```scala
  val spi2Wb = Module(new Spi2Wb(dwidth, awidth))
  val wbMdio1 = Module(new MdioWb(mainFreq, targetFreq))
  val wbMdio2 = Module(new MdioWb(mainFreq, targetFreq))

  val slavesVec = Vec(Seq(wbMdio1, wbMdio2))

  val wbIntercon = Module(new WbIntercon(spi2Wb.io.wbm, slavesVec))
```

The question is multiple:

- is it the right way to do it ?
- How to declare the Vec() in module parameters ?

I tryied this but does not work:

```
// Wishbone Intercone with one master and several slaves
// data bus is same size as master
class WbInterconOneMaster(val awbm: WbMaster,
                          val awbs: Vec[Seq[WbSlave]]) extends Module {
    val io = IO(new Bundle{
      val wbm = Flipped(new WbMaster(awbm.dwidth, awbm.awidth))
      val wbs = Vec.fill(awbs.size){awbs.map(_.cloneType())}
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [found a solution](https://github.com/Martoni/WbPlumbing/blob/750e01359c3ddd51f23b187b2af2e915ac44b314/src/main/scala/wbplumbing/wbplumbing.scala#L60) with MixedVec (experimental) module. I simply pass a Seq of WbSlave Bundle as a module parameter and I made a MixedVec (WbSlave can have different parameters in fact):

```scala
class WbInterconOneMaster(val awbm: WbMaster,
                          val awbs: Seq[WbSlave]) extends Module {
    val io = IO(new Bundle{
      val wbm = Flipped(new WbMaster(awbm.dwidth, awbm.awidth))
      val wbs = MixedVec(awbs.map{i => new WbSlave(i.dwidth, i.awidth)})
    })

    io.wbm.dat_i := 0.U
    io.wbm.ack_i := 0.U
    for(i <- 0 until io.wbs.size){
      io.wbs(i).dat_o := 0.U
      io.wbs(i).ack_o := 0.U
    }
}
```

That compile in [the testbench](https://github.com/Martoni/WbPlumbing/blob/750e01359c3ddd51f23b187b2af2e915ac44b314/src/test/scala/wbplumbing/testwbplumbing.scala#L66).

Comment: I think that looks like a good solution. It looks like the main feature of this is that you can extract the properties of each member of the `awbs` seq separately. This is exactly the case that MixedVec was designed to handle. Care must be taken when connecting things to and from a MixedVec do to those potential differences

Answer (score 1):

Try thinking about your parameters as generators of the types that you need. The following is a toy example of this idea. In this case the one constructor parameter `bgen` is a generator method that will return an instance of a Bundle. It shows the use of this generator as is and also as part of a `Vec`

```
class BundleX extends Bundle {
  val a = UInt(8.W)
  val b = UInt(8.W)
}

class ModuleX(bgen: () => BundleX, numInputs: Int) extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle{
    val in1  = Input(Vec(numInputs, bgen()))
    val out1 = Output(bgen())
  })
  // output fields a and b are the the sum of all the corresponding inputs
  io.out1.a := io.in1.foldLeft(0.U) { case (res, value) => res +% value.a}
  io.out1.b := io.in1.foldLeft(0.U) { case (res, value) => res +% value.b}
}

class BundleXSpec extends ChiselPropSpec {
  property("testname") {
    elaborate(new ModuleX(() => new BundleX, 4))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I still have a long way to learn scala to understand perfectly ;) I found another solution that seems to work too.